# removeClass isn't working on parent element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, removeclass

Example: http://www.royalnashef.com/sada/dotmaps/infobox/

On the right side, you'll see a nav group with a paperclip icon and a check icon.
If you click on one, a hidden div `.project-actions-sections` will display itself correctly. You can click between them once the `.project-actions-sections` div is displayed and it will give you a tabbed effect correctly.

**The problem is** when you click on an active link. When you do, the `.project-actions-sections` div goes back to being hidden correctly, but I can't seem to remove the `.active` class from the link's `parent li` in the navigation.

Here's my jquery:

```
$(".project-actions-nav .pullout-btn a").click(function() {
   if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('active');   
    $('.project-actions-sections').addClass("hide");
   } else {
    $('.project-actions-sections').removeClass("hide");
   }       
});
```

Here's the html:

```
<div id="infobox-accordion" class="project-actions clearfix">
        <!-- Tab Nav -->
        <ul class="nav nav-pills project-actions-nav" role="tablist">
          <li class="pullout-btn active"><a href="#project-uploads-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="pill"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span></a></li>
          <li class="pullout-btn"><a href="#project-completion-pullout" role="tab" data-toggle="pill"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a></li>    
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content project-actions-sections">
          <div class="tab-pane fade pullout-section active in" id="project-uploads-tab">
            <p>Test Tab #1</p>  
            </div>
          <div id="project-completion-pullout" class="tab-pane fade pullout-section">
              <p>Test Tab #2</p>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

I'm using jQuery 1.11.1 and bootstrap for scaffolding and base js.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: it is working see:http://jsfiddle.net/7ytLpsdb/

Comment: Yah, seemed simple enough. I think it might have something to do with the bootstrap script that adds the class .active on click. Bootstrap script is telling the li to add the class, and my script is telling the li to remove it. Do you have any suggestions as to how to deal with that?

Comment: That's not a particularly intuitive interface, anyway. I wouldn't expect an active tab to toggle the panel like that. Consider putting a dismiss icon elsewhere or a toggle handle on the panel.

Answer (score 1):

So.... I had to setTimeout() on the function where I removed the class .active. The reason for this is that Bootstrap's js was adding the class .active on each click, including the ones where I was trying to remove the class.

Here's the new code:

```
$(".pullout-btn a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   if ($(e.target).closest('li').hasClass('active')) {   
    $('.project-actions-sections').addClass("hide");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(e.target).closest('li').removeClass('active');
        }, 10);

   } else {
    $('.project-actions-sections').removeClass("hide");
   }       
});
```